# Spring's AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor and constructor injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

Everybody knows that @Autowired(@Inject etc) annotation is processed by AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor. It parses and set fields and setters annotated with @Autowired but what about constructors? This is bean **PostProcessor**, that means that it is called after bean was already created, but constructors can also be marked as @Autowired, so how such beans are created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. For clarification's sake, to re-word it:

- How does Spring provide the capability to do dependency injection on
  constructor parameters when it seems like dependencies are injected
  only ***after*** the bean is created?!

If you look at the **[AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java)** you'll find that there is a method called `#determineCandidateConstructors` that doesn't get called *anywhere* from inside that class itself.

The reason it's not called there is because it's referenced in the **[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java)**; a class that's used for the actual creation/instantion of the bean!

I would imagine Juergen and the Spring guys decided it made architectural sense to put the `#determineCandidateConstructors` in the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` class because it fits in with the concept function of the real purpose of `Autowire-ing` an injected dependency.

FYI, these concepts of field `@Autowire` vs. constructor `@Autowire` is so tightly tied together, that there is a whole discussion in the Spring DI world on whether to use constructor vs. dependency injection. See the section entitled **Constructor-based or setter-based DI** [of this article](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html), [Oliver Gierke's comment](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/) (i.e. head of Spring Data project), and [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=constructor+vs+field+injection&oq=constructor+vs+field+injection) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i think i understand it. AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor set autowired fields and setter, but object itself is created by autowireConstructor method of AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory using determineCandidateConstructors.

But what is the purpose of autowireByName and autowireByType method s of AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory? Does they works only when we set autowire strategy using xml?

Comment: Great question. From poking around, it seems like those consequentially get called during test creation and from AOP aspect creation. From the framework itself, it seems like that processor is the core class that is leveraged for all of the autowire-related DI.